# Question about AES and Cryptsetup

Tags: aes

I've read that AES can work with three key sizes: 128 bits, 192 bits and 256 bits.

I'm trying to set up a LUKS partition with [**CryptSetup**](https://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/), using “aes-xts-plain64” cipher.

Why can I create keys of any length with CryptSetup, except for the fact they have to be a multiple of 8?

Comment: This question appears to be **off-topic** because it is not about cryptography as defined in our help-center. [*“If your question is about usage of a specific cryptographic software (not its cryptographic internals), Super User is the right site.”*](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I have flagged the question for moderator attention with an according migration request. (So, please don’t cross-post your question; it will be moved accordingly by a mod if applicable.)

Comment: [man cryptsetup](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/cryptsetup8.html) (LUKS uses PBKDF2)

Comment: And if you have any questions related to what’s explained in [the man-pages that @otus pointed you to](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18507/question-about-aes-and-cryptsetup#comment41403_18507), you might want to take a look at the [*“CryptSetup FAQs”*](https://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions)…